# com_ajax and JFactory::getUser()

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin, com-plugins

I'm using com_ajax for requests, and I've run into a problem.

I'm trying to determine if the user making an AJAX request is logged in. When I call JFactory::getUser(), it's returning a guest user, ID=0. Similarly JApplication->isAdmin() returns false. I'm guessing that's because com_ajax resides in the site side, not the administrator side. Is that right?

Is there any way to use com_ajax and distinguish if someone is authenticated? Alternatively, is there an equivalent to com_ajax on the administrator side? Do I have to write my own Ajax on an administrative component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you using the correct naming conventions for you Ajax task in the URL and PHP function, you should have something like this:

**helper.php**

```
public static function myFunctionAjax()
{

}
```

**Javascript file**

```
var request = {
    'option' : 'com_ajax',
    'module' : 'mymodule',
    'method' : 'myFunction',
    'format' : 'raw'
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: request,
    success: function(response) {
        // etc
    }
});
```

`myFunction` needs to use the same name as the PHP function you wish to execute (`myFunctionAjax()`).

The only different being is that PHP function needs `Ajax` on the end.

Then inside your PHP function, you can check if the user is logged in, like so:

```
public static function myFunctionAjax()
{
    $user = JFactory::getUser();

    if (!$user->guest)
    {
        // perform some magic
    }
    else
    {
        // Sorry, you must be logged in
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I got the error: 

LogicException: Module mod_com_connectdaily is not published, you do not have access to it, or it's not assigned to the current menu item.

I ended up implementing a controller in the component to implement AJAX for this call.

Comment: I am also having same issue as @GeorgeSexton had.

Comment: @vishnu - I have updated the Javascript with some changes that fix issues I've personally run into myself. Please check again.

Comment: Nice one @Lodder . I adapted it to apply it to plugin. Its the roughly the same code. You saved my day.

Comment: @Lodder can we also use something else instead of `module`? I need to use a method from a custom form field.

Comment: @thednp Yes this is still possible. Feel free to post a new question if you're running into issues and need help.

Comment: @Lodder https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28926/use-com-ajax-with-a-custom-field