# Use com_ajax with a custom field

Tags: javascript, ajax, com-ajax

I've created a custom form field for templates, which is meant to handle SCSS compile. In short, I've opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/thednp/scss-wasm-compile/issues/1) where I had a little chat with one of the Joomla devs about wasm compile.

Here is a basic structure of my custom field:

```
namespace Joomla\Template\Cassiopeia\Site\Field;

\defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

class ScssCompileField extends FormField
{
    protected $type = 'ScssCompile';
    protected $template;
    protected $scssContent = '';

    public function setup(\SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null)
    {
        if (!parent::setup($element, $value, $group))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // this is the template
        $this->template = $this->form->getValue('template');

        // here are the inputFile and outputFile
        $this->inputFile = 'template.scss'; // the path is handled by the resolve
        $this->outputFile = JPATH_SITE . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/css/template.css';

        // here's adding the scripts and such
        HTMLHelper::_('script', 'templates/' . $this->template . '/js/system/sass.js');
        HTMLHelper::_('script', 'templates/' . $this->template . '/js/system/sass.worker.js');
        HTMLHelper::_('script', 'templates/' . $this->template . '/js/system/scss-compile.js', array(), array("type" => "module"));
        return true;
    }  

    public static function scssResponseAjax(){
        $this->concatContent($this->inputFile);
        return json_encode($this->scssContent);
    }  

    public static function scssWriteAjax($response){
        if (file_exists($this->outputFile) && is_writable($this->outputFile)) {
            file_put_contents($this->outputFile, $response);
        }
    }  

    // this is the button the user will interact with
    protected function getInput(){
        return '<button id="compileButton" class="btn btn-success">Compile</button>';
    }

    // this method will fill the SCSS content
    protected function concatContent(){}

    // other methods that handle paths resolve and such
}
```

Now, as the author of the wasm script instructed, I've create a JS module `scss-compile.js`:

```
'use strict';

function compileSCSS(){ 
  const compileOps = {
    style: Sass.style.expanded,
    precision: -1,
    comments: false,
    indent: '  ',
    linefeed: '\n',
  };

  // const response = await fetch('com_ajax...', {'GET' ... });

  // compile given SCSS content
  Sass.compile(response, compileOps, function callback(result) {
    return result.text
  });
}

document.getElementById('compileButton').addEventListener('click', compileSCSS);
```

Now I don't know what the `await fetch` function looks like and what `com_ajax` expects me to pass in to connect to the `ScssCompileField` class, nor do I know if my methods which this script is supposed to interact with are correct.

After some research, I noticed people mention about the Joomla `Input` class with its `set`, `get` and other methods within `com_ajax` context, I wonder if that would be useful for my custom field methods.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com_ajax` looks for a `helper.php` file in your root template directory and then searches for the method inside there, so you firstly need to create a `helper.php` with the following code:

```
class TplCassiopeiaHelper
{
    public static function scssResponseAjax()
    {
        return file_get_contents(JPATH_SITE . '/templates/cassiopeia/scss/template.scss');
    }
}
```

Then, remove the following line:

```
HTMLHelper::_('script', 'templates/' . $this->template . '/js/system/sass.worker.js');
```

Then in your `scss-compile.js`:

```
'use strict';

async function compileSCSS() {
  const sass = new Sass()

  const compileOps = {
    style: sass.style.expanded,
    precision: -1,
    comments: false,
    indent: '  ',
    linefeed: '\n',
  }

  const response = await fetch('index.php?option=com_ajax&template=cassiopeia&method=scssResponse&format=raw', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'plan/text',
    }
  })
  const content = await response.text()

  // Log the SCSS
  console.log(content)

  // Compile
  sass.compile(content, compileOps, function callback(result) {
    // Log the CSS
    console.log(result.text)

    // Now fire another fetch request to send the CSS and save the file in PHP
  })
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('compileButton').addEventListener('click', compileSCSS)
})
```

Comment: Thanks man. I'm finishing some commit to Joomla and will get back to this. I will provide feeedback asap. Cheers!

Comment: For some reason, on click it throws me out of the template style panel after "thinking" a bit, for sure that `sass.compile` you got there won't work with sass.js, it needs the data pre-loaded, which is what is missing from my above PHP and added here https://github.com/thednp/scss-wasm-compile/blob/master/templates/cassiopeia/src/Field/CompileField.php. Basically I've added all those class functions to `TplCassiopeiaHelper` and `setup()` is now `init()`. I'm executing `init()` then `concatContent` then return it. But can't get any response anywhere for now. Researching...

Comment: I think this has to be related to https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/32291 and my commit https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/30816

Comment: Hmm well it was working perfect fine for me. I got the CSS output. It doesn't need anything preloaded, but yeah the namespace thing is probably your issue at the moment. I haven't namespaced my template

Comment: It's not possible you got the CSS content, the compiler is incomplete without an importer to handle all `@import`. Or do you mean your setup works which is slightly different implementation perhaps.

Comment: If you commit your code, I can clone your repo and check what you have so far

Comment: Thanks man, much appreciated. I would suggest we wait and let them handle all those nasty inter-dependent PRs. I think it's a waste of time to deal with this at this point, but we MUST contribute to the Joomla GIT with testing and PRs. I've heard you like my color-picker ;)

Comment: Just to pass some time I've given this a try, (I removed the namespace, moved my field to fields, addfileldpath...). The same thing, my `scssResponseAjax` should return "Hello World", but it still does the same thing.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the fact that my scripts don't get loaded. Lemme investigate. Yes indeed `Uri::root`.

Comment: I'm now getting scss-compile1.js:16 GET `index.php?option=com_ajax&template=cassiopeia&method=scssResponse&format=raw 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: I managed to get this going, I'm marking this as answered. Thank you